# How to wait for function to complete before proceding

Tags: r, loops, pause

I'm currently using the `ode()` function from the `deSolve` library in r.

This function takes up to a minute or two to process a set of linked differential equations.

I need to halt/pause the program until this function is completed as I have it running in a loop up to 20 times over my data.

Is there a method to pause r when the duration in milliseconds is unknown?
Is there a method to pause r until a variable is written over?

Any direction on where to look is appreciated.

Comment: When you say "pause R until complete", do you mean to put the `ode` process on hold and return to the R prompt?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't already happening? The standard behavior is for R to wait for a line to be completed before moving on to the next line.

Comment: R will wait till one statement is done before completing the next. Could you say more about why you think you need to add in a delay? Is there some error you are getting?